# Change Connection String dynamically from user input using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, database-connection, multi-tenant

Requirements - 
My Application have multiple clients having their own database servers and database name, but all databases have same structure( as in tables and Keys ) .
I want a plug-in service, where when client login and register its connection string in our local database. Our application fetch the connection String from the database to that particular client and connect to the database and fetch the data from it.

Tried AbstractRoutingDataSource, but it itself needs connection String to be stored before.

Comment: there is an example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744973/dynamic-datasource-in-spring-boot-jpa/48745064#48745064_)

Comment: connection url is already hard coded. For my requirements, server can be different

Comment: I have the same question