# Spring boot, JPA dynamic data source connection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am a newbie to `spring`, `hibernate` and `JPA`.

I have built a project with `SpringBoot` and `JPA`.
I have a base database which holds different customer database names depending on the customer id.
Hence when starting the `spring boot` application I connect to the base database using `JPA` repository(straight forward).

Depending on the database name i got in the previous step, i now have to connect to the new database to fetch the customer information using `JPA`.

Because I don't know the customer database names upfront, i have a problem do this.
All the database are `MySQL`.

Can someone suggest a best way to achieve this?

Comment: here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744973/dynamic-datasource-in-spring-boot-jpa/48745064#48745064) that shows an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*There are two approachs that you can try.*

**Approach 1:**

You can use `DataSourceBuilder` to get the DataSource.

```
DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()  
    .driverClassName(driver-class-name)   
    .url(env.getProperty(dataSoruceUrl).build();
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection(username, password);
```

Using connection you can execute the SQL statements.

**Approach 2:**

You can try AbstractRoutingDatasource provided by Spring. [Here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source) is a guide explaining about it.

Hope it helps!!