# What is the right design for handling dynamic datasources in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to design a Spring Boot REST service using. I have a use case where-in I have to deal with databases created out of some legacy tool. There are about 100+ databases and my connection to the database depends on the Request Param.

I have tried create dynamic datasource and use JDBCTemplate for querying the database. I would like to know:

1. If there are any better way of achieving the same?
2. How should I handle the connections as there will be 100+ databases and I need to close the connections. As of now I plan to keep only say connections to 30-40 datasources(code not included)

The sample code for my implementation is as below. The class MyJDBCTemplateSource.java provides the JDBCTemplate for the respective database. The class DataSourceComponent is just a map that is maintained to avoid creation of datasource.

```
public class MyJDBCTemplateSource {

private final DataSourceComponent dataSourceComponent;
private HikariDataSource dataSource;

public MyJDBCTemplateSource() {
    dataSourceComponent = BeanUtil.getBean(DataSourceComponent.class);
}

public JdbcTemplate getJDBCTemplate(Long accountId, Long shardId) {
    initDataSource(accountId, shardId);
    JdbcTemplate template = dataSourceComponent.getJDBCTemplate(accountId);
    if(template == null)
    {   
        template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        dataSourceComponent.addTemplate(accountId, template);
    }
    return template;
}

private void initDataSource(Long accountId, Long shardId) {
    String dbUrlPattern = "jdbc:mysql://mydb%d:3306";
    String accountPattern = "acc_%05d";
    String jdbcDriverClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "xxxx";
    String password = "ppppppp";

    dataSource = (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder
            .create().username(userName).password(password).url(String.format(dbUrlPattern, shardId) + "/"
                    + String.format(accountPattern, accountId) + "?useSSL=false")
            .driverClassName(jdbcDriverClass).type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
}
```

}

```
@Component
```

public class DataSourceComponent {

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<Long, JdbcTemplate> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void addTemplate(Long accountId, JdbcTemplate template) {
    cache.put(accountId, template);
}

public JdbcTemplate getJDBCTemplate(Long accountId) {
    return cache.get(accountId);
}
```

}

Comment: Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744973/dynamic-datasource-in-spring-boot-jpa/48745064#48745064)

Comment: Thanks I had a look into it before posting this. I like that solution but I have additional question of managing connections. The databases are created by the leagacy tool and they keep growing. So I cannot configure them via yml file. Also I cannot keep my datasources cached permanently. At some point I need to release them. Any suggestions from that perspective

Comment: You're not keeping connections open by having datasource objects in your JVM, you could have thousands. The datasource will manage it's connections, and should release after each use.